# Difference between ketone rings in wavelength using an IR device

Tags: organic-chemistry

It is said that the smaller the ring size, the greater the wavelength of the carbonyl group, but why does cyclobutanone have a higher wavelength than cyclopropanone?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does cyclobutanone have a higher wavelength than cyclopropanone?

Seemingly, you were informed wrong. According to [MSU website](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/spectrpy/infrared/irspec1.htm), following wave numbers listed for different cyclic ketones:

[image: Wave numbers for different cyclic ketones]

The increase in frequency ranges from $30$ to $\pu{45 cm-1}$ for a 5-membered ring, to $50$ to $\pu{60 cm-1}$ for a 4-membered ring, and nearly $\pu{130 cm-1}$ for a 3-membered ring. According to [this](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p3bn0olt/Cyclic-ketones-The-size-of-rings-affects-the-CO-stretching-frequency-The/), the increase in stretching frequency of exo-carbonyl group is because small rings have more $\mathrm{p}$-character in their ring bonds, which means the bonds outside the ring (exo-bonds) have more $\mathrm{s}$-character and are stronger.

---

**Edit:** There is a relation between stretching frequency and corresponding wavelengths:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Stretching frequency, }\pu{cm-1} & \text{corresponding wavelength, }\pu{nm} \\
\hline
1716 & 5820 \\
1748 & 5720 \\
1783 & 5600 \\
1850 & 5400 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Also, you can find this convertor [here](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/spectrpy/infrared/infrared.htm#:%7E:text=Frequency%20in%20cm%2D1&text=The%20frequency%20scale%20at%20the,the%20numbers%20are%20more%20manageable.).

Comment: The questioner seems unsure about wavenumber[frequency] and wavelength